# Null a file in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

In bash i can truncate a file with:

`$ > file`

However the same command in `zsh` hangs.

Is it possible to configure `zsh` to emulate `bash` when truncating files?

Comment: I believe the command you are thinking of in bash is `: > file`.  Not sure what its equivalent is in zsh though.

Comment: Yeah, use `:> file` in either as that is a) portable and b) avoids the read from stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the feedback here, I discovered that setting the `zsh` `NULLCMD` parameter to `:` emulates bash.

```
% NULLCMD=:
% >file
% ls -l file
  -rw-r--r--  1 pfalstad        0 May 24 05:41 file
```

Source: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_13.html

`NULLCMD` is indeed set to `cat` by default

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` is not actually hanging, it's accepting input. If you want `bash` behaviour use `^D` (ctrl-d) to send an `EOF`.